# $ f(x) = f(x + 1), \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \land \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L \Rightarrow f(x) = L, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I want to prove that $ f $ is continuous $\,  \land f(x) = f(x + 1), \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \land \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L \Rightarrow f(x) = L, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, is my proof valid?

Assume $ \exists x \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $ f\left(x\right) \neq L $. Choose $ \epsilon = \left|f\left(x\right) - L\right| \neq 0 $, because the absolute value function is a metric. Therefore, $ \exists N \gt 0 : \forall z \gt N, \left|f\left(z\right) - L\right| \lt \epsilon $. Choose $ z = x + \left|\lceil Nx \rceil\right| \gt N \Rightarrow \left|f\left(z\right) - L\right| =  \left|f\left(x\right) - L \right| \lt \epsilon$ - contradiction.

Comment: The expression $x + |\lceil N x \rceil|$ appears to not be what you want, as it is not greater than $N$ when $x$ is small. Perhaps you want $z = x + \lceil N - x\rceil + 1$, or something like this?

Comment: @TheoBendit what about $ x + |\lceil N \rceil \lceil x \rceil | $?

Comment: If $x \in (-1, 0]$, then this is equal to $x$, and probably will not be greater than $N$.

Comment: I'd just add $N + 1 + |x| $ instead of $\left|\lceil Nx \rceil\right|$. But the idea is sound.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$ f(x) = f(x+n).$$

Therefore, since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$, we have,

$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x+n) = L.$$

**The continuity condition of $f$ is not required to prove this problem, however it's obviously continuous because it's a constant function.**

Comment: Does the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x+n)=L$ because you have fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$ at the beginning of the proof and so, for any fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it is $x+n \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and hence you can use the hypothesis $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=L$ with $x+n$ and $n \to \infty$ because the limit must be the same for any sequence $a_n \to \infty$?

Comment: Right. If the limit exists then it also exists for any sequence $a_n$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You're approach is good, but you need to be a little more careful on picking $z$, because $$
x + |\lceil N x\rceil| > N
$$
does not hold for general $x$ (for example, suppose $x=0$). Your goal is to find some integer $m$ such that $x+m> N$. There are lots of ways to get there explicitly, but perhaps the easiest is to rearrange your goal to $m > N-x$. From here, you can obviously just make $m = \lceil N-x\rceil$ and it works.